# Adding numbers to similar names in Perl

Tags: database, perl, output, increment, blast

I am trying to convert a blast file to gff3 using Perl and I am quite new to programming since I'm doing science.
My current code is below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $db = "BLAST";
my $prog = "blastn";
my $subid = "";

open(my $inFile, $ARGV[0]) || die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]' $!";
open(my $outFile, ">$ARGV[1]") || die "Could not find file '>$ARGV[1]' $!";

print $outFile "##gff-version 3\n#\n#\n";

while(<$inFile>){

    my ($qseqid, $sseqid, $pident, $length, $mismatch, $gaps, $qstart, $qend, $sstart, $send, $evalue, $bitscore) = split(/\t/);

    if($qstart < $qend){
        $sign = "+";
    } elsif($qstart > $qend){
        $sign = "-";
    } else {
        die "Unexpected qstart and end";
    }

    $bitscore =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;

    print $outFile "$sseqid\t$db\t$prog\t$qstart\t$qend\t$bitscore\t$sign\t.\t$subid\n";
}
```

I have an output of

```
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  1       3954    7302    +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  4178    6577    4433    +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  3953    4114    300     +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  4115    4178    119     +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1
scf_62525_1067.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1       1665    3075    +   .   scf_62525_1067.contig_1
scf_62525_163.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  7       357     612     +   .   scf_62525_163.contig_1
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1       1321    2436    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1319    2231    1687    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1275    1321    87.9    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1
```

and I want to change it to this output

```
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  1       3954    7302    +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1.t1.d1
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  4178    6577    4433    +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1.t1.d2
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  3953    4114    300     +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1.t1.d3
scf_62525_290.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  4115    4178    119     +   .   scf_62525_290.contig_1.t1.d4
scf_62525_1067.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1       1665    3075    +   .   scf_62525_1067.contig_1.t1.d1
scf_62525_163.contig_1  BLAST   blastn  7       357     612     +   .   scf_62525_163.contig_1.t1.d1
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1       1321    2436    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1.t1.d1
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1319    2231    1687    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1.t1.d2
scf_62525_4028.contig_1 BLAST   blastn  1275    1321    87.9    +   .   scf_62525_4028.contig_1.t1.d3
```

Is there a simple way of doing so?
Thanks.

---

Here's some sample input:

```
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  3954    0   0   1   3954    23690   27643   0.0 7302
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  2400    0   0   4178    6577    28076   30475   0.0 4433
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  162 0   0   3953    4114    27722   27883   1e-79   300
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  64  0   0   4115    4178    27957   28020   4e-25   119
Ppluv_s011067g00001.1   scf_62525_1067.contig_1 100.00  1665    0   0   1   1665    4944    6608    0.0 3075
Ppluv_s010163g00001.1   scf_62525_163.contig_1  97.77   359 0   8   7   357 797 439 8e-175  612
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  1321    0   0   1   1321    2322    1002    0.0 2436
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  913 0   0   1319    2231    924 12  0.0 1687
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  47  0   0   1275    1321    992 946 4e-16   87.9
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_3545.contig_1 79.23   1343    241 38  1   1321    1   1327    0.0 902
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_1712.contig_1 74.27   1951    403 99  340 2227    3076    4990    0.0 732
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_817.contig_1  82.74   730 87  39  1378    2105    23175   22483   2e-174  614
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_177.contig_1  76.37   804 178 12  1320    2117    29453   28656   1e-116  422
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_177.contig_1  75.28   615 134 18  1326    1937    36037   35438   2e-73   278
```

Comment: Can you describe how the  `t1.dX` identifiers should be assigned?

Comment: One thought: this might be something that [BioPerl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/BioPerl/BioPerl.pm) can already do, and one question: how are the new extensions (`.tx.dy`) determined?

Comment: while $sseqid is the same you add 1 to the counter else it will reset back to 0 @choroba

Comment: @MattJacob I just made those extensions so I can identify them better while I run them on a genome browser

Comment: @programnub OK, so it's simply incrementing a counter for each sub-value?

Comment: @MattJacob yes, but I'm not sure how to compare the values inside $sseqid

Comment: @programnub Can you include some sample input data? About 10-20 lines should be fine...

Comment: @programnub Thanks. I rolled back your latest edit and integrated the sample input. You don't want to keep updating your question with proposed answers, because then it masks the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [hash of hashes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) to keep track of how many times you've seen each ID pair:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $db = "BLAST";
my $prog = "blastn";
my %unique;

print "##gff-version 3\n#\n#\n";

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;

    my $sseqid   = $fields[1];
    my $qstart   = $fields[6];
    my $qend     = $fields[7];
    my $bitscore = $fields[11];
    my $sign;

    if ($qstart < $qend) {
        $sign = "+";
    } elsif ($qstart > $qend) {
        $sign = "-";
    } else {
        die "Unexpected qstart and end";
    }

    my @id_parts = split(/[_.]/, $sseqid);
    my $sub_id = ++$unique{$id_parts[1]}{$id_parts[2]};

    print join("\t", $sseqid, $db, $prog, $qstart, $qend, $bitscore, $sign, '.', "$sseqid.$sub_id"), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  3954    0   0   1   3954    23690   27643   0.0 7302
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  2400    0   0   4178    6577    28076   30475   0.0 4433
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  162 0   0   3953    4114    27722   27883   1e-79   300
Ppluv_s010290g00001.1   scf_62525_290.contig_1  100.00  64  0   0   4115    4178    27957   28020   4e-25   119
Ppluv_s011067g00001.1   scf_62525_1067.contig_1 100.00  1665    0   0   1   1665    4944    6608    0.0 3075
Ppluv_s010163g00001.1   scf_62525_163.contig_1  97.77   359 0   8   7   357 797 439 8e-175  612
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  1321    0   0   1   1321    2322    1002    0.0 2436
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  913 0   0   1319    2231    924 12  0.0 1687
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_4028.contig_1 100.00  47  0   0   1275    1321    992 946 4e-16   87.9
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_3545.contig_1 79.23   1343    241 38  1   1321    1   1327    0.0 902
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_1712.contig_1 74.27   1951    403 99  340 2227    3076    4990    0.0 732
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_817.contig_1  82.74   730 87  39  1378    2105    23175   22483   2e-174  614
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_177.contig_1  76.37   804 178 12  1320    2117    29453   28656   1e-116  422
Ppluv_s014028g00001.1   scf_62525_177.contig_1  75.28   615 134 18  1326    1937    36037   35438   2e-73   278
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it by using a counter.  From what I see in this code is that the $subid are numbered incrementally if they are the same, the extensions appear to be the same.  Maybe you could do something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $db = "BLAST";
my $prog = "blastn";
my $subid = "";

open(my $inFile, $ARGV[0]) || die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]' $!";
open(my $outFile, ">$ARGV[1]") || die "Could not find file '>$ARGV[1]' $!";

print $outFile "##gff-version 3\n#\n#\n";

my $cnt = 0;
my ($tmp,$fn);

while(<$inFile>){

    my ($qseqid, $sseqid, $pident, $length, $mismatch, $gaps, $qstart, $qend, $sstart, $send, $evalue, $bitscore) = split(/\t/);
    my $suffix = ".t1.d${cnt}";
    if (!$tmp){
        $tmp = $subid;
    }

    if ($tmp eq $subid){
        $cnt++;
        $fn = "${subid}${suffix}";
        $tmp = $subid;
    }
    else {
        $cnt = 1;
        $fn = "${subid}${suffix}";
        $tmp = $subid;
    }

    if($qstart < $qend){
        $sign = "+";
    } elsif($qstart > $qend){
        $sign = "-";
    } else {
        die "Unexpected qstart and end";
    }

    $bitscore =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;

    print $outFile "$sseqid\t$db\t$prog\t$qstart\t$qend\t$bitscore\t$sign\t.\t$fn\n";
}
```

This is untested but you get the idea

Comment: It will always go to the last else statement right? since $tmp is not set to anything yet? "if (!$tmp)" ... correct me if Im wrong

Comment: the first time through it should set $tmp to $subid because it has not be set, I see what your saying.  Probably change the elsif to just an if so if ($tmp eq $subid)

Comment: I forgot to update the $tmp variable as well, the above code should reflect that

Comment: I tried doing if ($tmp eq $subid), but it incremented the whole $fn. Sorry I'm quite new to this

Comment: can you show me an example of the output?  Also if you have the input to look at it would also make more sense, there could be a better approach, I am basing it off of the information provided

Comment: $cnt should also = 0.  Updated above, I tested on a sample file I made and it works, assuming the file you are using is similar.